# Android/SQLite. Insert multiple values in database with filtration?

Tags: android, sql, insert

I try to insert into a database some values(message body and date) only if the phone number (number) doesn't exist in it, but my code doesn't working. Can you give some advice?

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO version2 (number, body, date) values ("+number+","+body+","+ date+")  SELECT "+number+" WHERE NOT EXISTS "
            + "(SELECT 1 FROM version2 WHERE number = "+number+")", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

Seems like your select query is incorrect while insert record.

```
 INSERT INTO version2 (number, body, date) values ("+number+","+body+","+ date+")  WHERE number IS NOT NULL or number <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method which will check for the duplicate phone number.

```
private boolean isPhoneExists ( long number ) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select phone from version2 where number = " + number, null );

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    return true;
    else
     return false;
}
```

//Now your inserting statement

```
 if ( !isPhoneExists ( "987654321" ) )
 {
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO version2 (number, body, date) values ("+number+","+body+","+ date+")
   .... 
 }
```